# C programming on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04

I have problems related to c programming on Ubuntu 12.04. While compiling c program consisting 'pow' I faced difficulties. Then I searched the Internet and got the solution with '-lm'. But that's the compiling part. How to execute and Run that program that has 'pow' in it? I failed to execute and run. The message said "No such file or directory". What can I do? Again, is there any easy way of learning C programming on Ubuntu, where I can fully concentrate on coding. I don't have to think bout compiling, executing and running the code. Should I use IDE for that? What do you say?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Save your code as .c (say Example.c)

Step 2: compile it as `gcc Example.c`

Step 3: run by `./a.out`

For Adding libraries as you mentioned.

```
gcc Example.c -lm
```

Suppose you want to program using pthread then

```
gcc Example.c -lpthread
```

For Debugging with gdb, you need debug symbols. so while compiling you need to use -g

```
gcc -g Example.c
```

If you want to change your executable name, i.e a.out to some other name, then use -o

```
gcc Example.c -o myfirstpgm
```

finally combined of all

```
gcc -g Example.c -o myfirstpgm -lm
```

Comment: When I compile without adding '-lm', then I got the following message                                                           In function `main':
13.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status                                                               But when I use "gcc -Wall 13.c -o 13.out -lm" then it compiles without any further error message. But while executing and running I get the same message every time saying 'No such file or directory'. My executing and running code are as follows receptively: chmod +x 13   and   ./13

Comment: yes. you need `-lm`, because you are using pow().

Comment: `gcc Example.c -lm` will work for you.

Comment: If you name it 13.out you need to run ./13.out on the cmd line. Not just ./13

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think learning to code while learning to compile with the command line should be done together.  Doing so, gives you a better feel for what your code is doing and needs to run.  IDE's are great - some people love them.  I am not one of those people.  But they have their advantages.

To answer your `pow` problem, rjayavrp's answer is great, just also remember to `#include<math.h>` at the top of your code, in addition to `-lm` at compile time as has been suggested previously.

For your learning pleasure, I find [this](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/) to be very helpful when learning C programming.

Good luck!

Comment: Okay I got the answer from @Balder. The codes to compile, execute and run are as follows
gcc -Wall 13.c -o 13.out -lm chmod +x 13.out ./13.out That's it. My problem was not adding 'out' after the 'to be executed/run' file name. Thanks. My problem has been solved now.

Comment: Another way of saying it is the editor should be a convenience, not a crutch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for an IDE, you can use [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) for this. It uses a [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) compiler and also gives you options for other compilers.